# Javascript. Наследование метода, изменение

Tags: javascript, ооп, наследование

Изучаю тонкости ООП в Javascript.

В этом коде при щелчке по списку, копируется текст в вышестоящий `input`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> <title>События</title>
<style>
div, input {box-sizing:border-box; outline:none; width:150px;} .listBox, input {border:1px solid #ccc;} .listBox div:hover {background:#f0f0f0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="s1">
  <input value="" readonly>
  <div class="listBox">
    <div>Автомобили</div> <div>Компьютеры</div> <div>Бытовая техника</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="getValue()">Прочитать value из объека</button>
<script>
function mySelect(idx) {
  var el = document.getElementById(idx);
  var inp = el.children[0], listBox = el.querySelector('.listBox');
  this.onChangeValue = listBox.onclick = function(e) {
    inp.value = e.target.textContent;
    console.log('сообщение из mySelect');
  }
  this.text = function() {return inp.value};
}

var s1 = new mySelect('s1');
function getValue() {console.log(s1.text());}//OK

var parentChange = s1.onChangeValue;
s1.onChangeValue = function(e) {// неудачная попытка
  parentChange.call(this);
  console.log('сообщение из внешнего мира');
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Свойство `text` успешно вытаскивается из объекта через `s1.text()`. Хочется сделать нечто похожее и для метода `onChangeValue`.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы отловить изменение текста в `input` ?
Т.е. я щелкаю по элементу списка, и кроме фразы "*сообщение из mySelect*" должна ещё появляться фраза "*сообщение из внешнего мира*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал через `prototype`, полная демо версия https://jsfiddle.net/9xqgLa4d/1/
Здесь работает событие `onchange`, можно при желании задавать поиск и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

ммм... если я верно тебя понял и если принять во внимание, [что](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

> The change event is fired for **input**, **select**, and **textarea** elements when a change to the element's value is **committed by the user**.

то чтобы сделать то, что ты хочешь, тебе надо реализовать свою систему событий с использованием паттернов *pubslish/subscribe* или *observer* например. И тогда ты будешь сам вручную запускать своё событие (и активировать тем самым назначенный обработчик), как только ты поменяешь значение в инпуте. Я бы так сделал.